# Alt+Q doesn't close applications in KDE Plasma 5 on Fedora

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, plasma5

I use Fedora and KDE Plasma 5.

I want to close applications with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. I set this hotkey as KWin->Close Window, but after saving changes <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> still does nothing. Some applications close with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, some (ex Google Chrome) close with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, but <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> doesn't work. I can not understand why.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the fact that `Alt+Q` works in Fedora 30's KDE spin as well.

Answer (score 1):

Closing a window and closing an application aren't always the same thing.

I use Kubuntu 19.04, not Fedora, but I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to close windows.

[image: Setting Alt+Q to close windows]

That setting is reflected in *~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc*

> Window Close=Alt+F4\tAlt+Q,Alt+F4,Close Window

And <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> works to close windows of Firefox, KInfoCenter, Konsole, Kwrite, and System Settings.

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 19.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.15.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.57.0
Qt Version: 5.12.2
```

Is it possible you haven't installed KDE Plasma 5 completely?

---

**Edit:**

I installed the KDE spin of Fedora from [here](https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/30/Spins/x86_64/iso/Fedora-KDE-Live-x86_64-30-1.2.iso) in a VM to check whether <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> works there to close windows. And it does.

```
Operating System: Fedora 30
KDE Plasma Version: 5.15.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.58.0
Qt Version: 5.12.1
Kernel Version: 5.0.17-300.fc30.x86_64
OS Type: 64-bit
```

Comment: I think that I installed completely KDE Plasma 5. But I noticed that other shortcuts with `ALT` doesnt work too... I set `CTRL` + `ALT` + `Q` for lock screen and it doesnt work :(

Comment: My info: `Operating System: Fedora 30`
`KDE Plasma Version: 5.15.4`
`KDE Frameworks Version: 5.58.0`
`Qt Version: 5.12.1`

Comment: I don't know anything about Fedora. Could you look around and find out whether there's anything else you could install? Can you set **any** new shortcuts? And do `Alt+F4` and `Alt+F3` work? They're pretty basic and built-in, AFAICT.

Comment: I can set new shortcuts - I set `Win` + Numkeys for switch between workspaces and it works fine, but something wrong only with Alt hotkeys. Builtin ALT hotkeys (ex `Alt+F4`) work fine too. `CTRL+Q` close some apps too. I have feeling that there is conflict between Fedora's ALT and other KDE shortcuts, but I cant find info about that.

Comment: Normally, if you enter a shortcut already in use, the system warns you and asks if you want to reassign the shortcut. Sorry I can't be of more help!